# Converting full data set to List

Tags: c#, .net, list, dataset

I am trying to convert all fields of data set to a List so that I can extract any row later from the List. I am new to C#, so please be patient.

Here is what I have:

```
BLL_ProjectMaster BLL = new BLL_ProjectMaster();
DataSet ds = BLL.GetDataSet(); // It works fine and I can display in gridview
ProjList = new List<ProjectMasterRec>()
```

Now I want to move all rows from ds to `ProjList`.

Comment: How does `ProjectMasterRec` class looks like? How many tables your set has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to run a `LINQ To Object` query like below

```
var collection = (from DataRow row in DataSet.Tables[0].Rows select new ProjectMasterRec{  
                      Name = Convert.ToString(row["Name"])
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(a => new ProjectMasterRec(a)).ToList();
```

Since you missing `ProjectMasterRec` class structure in SO question, make sure while creating instance of constuctor of `ProjectMasterRec` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a foreach loop and go through all rows, it will look something like the code below:

```
DataSet ds = BLL.GetDataSet();
var projList = new List<ProjectMasterRec>();

foreach(DataRow row in ds.Rows) 
{
    // add each row to your list...
}
```